# Edit the data of the array inside of the loop - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, session

I'm trying to edit the data of the array using the session and loop.

The expected output in this code is, editing the specific data inside of the loop, but the problem is other data is being edited. Please help me out with this problem, thank you.

NOTE: If the `$cart_action` is `add`, new data will be added, but if the `$values['type']` is equal to the `$_POST['type']` the specific quantity of the product will be edited.

Example, I want to edit the qty of product_id MQFUQ, but I have no idea on how to edit this one, the product_id SHAREZ is always got edited.
//data
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[product_number] => NP1DC
[product_id] => 28AHT
[type] => SOLOZ
[qty] => 1
)

```
    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_number] => DZRW8
            [product_id] => 28AHT
            [type] => SHAREZ
            [qty] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_number] => 4G0RY
            [product_id] => MQFUQ
            [type] => 
            [qty] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [product_number] => ZS1C6
            [product_id] => 28AHT
            [type] => SOLOZ
            [qty] => 1
        )

)

//here's my code
$result = 0;
$values_type = "";
foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)
{
    $values_type = $values['type'];
    if($values["product_id"] == $_POST["product_id"] && $values['type'] == $_POST['type'])
    {
        $item_array = array(
            'product_number'            =>  $values['product_number'],
            'product_id'            =>  $_POST["product_id"],
            'type'          =>  $_POST["type"],
            'qty'       =>  $_POST['qty'] + $values['qty']
        );
        $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys] = $item_array;
        $result = $keys;
        $cart_action = "edit";
    }
    else {
        $values_type = $values['type'];
        $count = count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
        $item_array = array(
            'product_number'            =>  $product_number,
            'product_id'            =>  $_POST["product_id"],
            'type'          =>  $_POST["type"],
            'qty'       =>  $_POST['qty']
        );
        $result = $count;
        $cart_action = "add";
    }
}

if ($cart_action == "add") {
    $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$result] = $item_array;
    echo $cart_action ." ". $values_type;
}
elseif ($cart_action == "edit") {
    $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$result] = $item_array;
    echo $cart_action ." ". $values_type;
}
else {
    echo "";
}
```

Comment: It would help if you show the original array(representative sample `var_export()`) and the target array.

Comment: @jibsteroos Hi, I already edited my post, please check if you have time, thank you Sir.

Comment: First of all - if to relay on your code here, the product will be always added, not counted. You check two things against the session - type and product_id. But given var_dump says type is always different.
Secondly - why make it so hard? check session item-s product id, if there, session item qty+1, else add new product

Answer (score 1):

```
$values_type = "";
foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)
{
    $values_type = $values['type'];
    if($values["product_id"] == $_POST["product_id"] && $values['type'] == $_POST['type'])
    {
        $item_array = array(
            'product_number'            =>  $values['product_number'],
            'product_id'            =>  $_POST["product_id"],
            'type'          =>  $_POST["type"],
            'qty'       =>  $_POST['qty'] + $values['qty']
        );
        $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys] = $item_array;
        $result = $keys;
        $cart_action = "edit";
    }  else {
        $values_type = $values['type'];
        $count = count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
        $item_array = array(
            'product_number'            =>  $product_number,
            'product_id'            =>  $_POST["product_id"],
            'type'          =>  $_POST["type"],
            'qty'       =>  $_POST['qty']
        );
        array_push($_SESSION["shopping_cart"], $item_array); //adds the item array as a new element in the shopping_cart array
        $result = $count;
        $cart_action = "add";
    }
}
```

I hope this solves your problem. The problem was you were setting `$result` or `$cart_action` inside the loop. These values are changed with every iteration of loop, so your values may not be the same as you intended after the loop, these values will be determined by the last iteration only.

Comment: Hi thank you Sir, but the problem is still the same if I'm editing the value, the system is adding a new array, for example I add a product in my cart then if I click add to cart again, the same product will be added instead of editing the value.

Comment: the problem is, for example if the array is 3 and I put the if else statement inside of the loop, the 3 product_id is displaying instead of 1 product_id only.

Answer (score 0):

If type is not so important, then maybe something like that?

```
<?php
$result = 0;
$values_type = "";
foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values) {
    $values_type = $values['type'];
    if($values["product_id"] == $_POST["product_id"]) // remove that! && $values['type'] == $_POST['type'])
    {
/*
        $item_array = array(
            'product_number'            =>  $values['product_number'],
            'product_id'            =>  $_POST["product_id"],
            'type'          =>  $_POST["type"],
            'qty'       =>  $_POST['qty'] + $values['qty']
        );
*/
        $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]["qty"] += $_POST['qty'];
        $cart_action = "edit";
    }
    else {
        $values_type = $values['type'];
        $count = count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
        $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$count] = array(
            'product_number'            =>  $product_number,
            'product_id'            =>  $_POST["product_id"],
            'type'          =>  $_POST["type"],
            'qty'       =>  $_POST['qty']
        );
        $result = $count;
        $cart_action = "add";
    }
}
?>
```

**UPDATE**

Also, here is another thing to think of - if the type is some kind of separator (like color or size), then it is, in fact, a different product(item) in the cart, how else you know what and how much is needed.
Also - you should be able to edit sessions without using it always - like using & operator in foreach.